# Class member access inside the member function body

Tags: c++, class, language-lawyer, member

The following simple code example causes some doubts for me:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct A
{
    int a;
    A(int a)
    {
        A::a = a; //It is unclear, because in that case we're applying 
                  //scope resolution operator to A and does.

        this -> a = a; //It is clear, because this points to the current object.
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a(4);
    cout << a.a;
}
```

[demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/761875bc55237cec)

I know that the section 3.4.3.1/3 says:

> A class member name hidden by a name in a nested declarative region or
>   by the name of a derived class member can still be found if qualified
>   by the name of its class followed by the :: operator.

But it doesn't specify that the name looked up with "Qualified name lookup" (e.g. `A::a` in my case) inside the member function shall denote a member of current object. 
I'm looking for relevant reference in the Standard.

Comment: If not the current object, a member of *what* other object could it possibly refer to?

Comment: @jogojapan I mean, why outside of a member function body we receive a compile-time error (invalid use of non-static data member)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When searching for something specific to nonstatic class member functions, you should look first at the subclause governing...nonstatic class member functions. §9.3.1 [class.mfct.non-static]/p3:

> When an *id-expression* (5.1) that is not part of a class member access
>   syntax (5.2.5) and not used to form a pointer to member (5.3.1) is
>   used in a member of class `X` in a context where `this` can be used
>   (5.1.1), if name lookup (3.4) resolves the name in the *id-expression*
>   to a non-static non-type member of some class `C`, and if either the
>   *id-expression* is potentially evaluated or `C` is `X` or a base class of `X`,
>   the *id-expression* is transformed into a class member access expression
>   (5.2.5) using `(*this)` (9.3.2) as the *postfix-expression* to the left of
>   the `.` operator. [ *Note*: If `C` is not `X` or a base class of `X`, the class
>   member access expression is ill-formed. —*end note* ] Similarly during
>   name lookup, when an *unqualified-id* (5.1) used in the definition of a
>   member function for class `X` resolves to a static member, an enumerator
>   or a nested type of class `X` or of a base class of `X`, the
>   *unqualified-id is* transformed into a *qualified-id* (5.1) in which the
>   *nested-name-specifier* names the class of the member function.

Comment: Indeed, many thanks. I was looking for that in the sec. 10.2. I haven't known the Standard pretty good  yet...

Answer (score 0):

C++.11 §5.1.1¶8

> A *nested-name-specifier* that denotes a class, optionally followed by the keyword `template` (14.2), and then followed by the name of a member of either that class (9.2) or one of its base classes (Clause 10), is a *qualified-id*; 3.4.3.1 describes name lookup for class members that appear in *qualified-ids*. The result is the member. The type of the result is the type of the member. The result is an lvalue if the member is a static member function or a data member and a prvalue otherwise.